# Is npm install -g @angular/cli command upgrades Angular version if already I have installed Angular?

Tags: angular-cli

I have already installed angular in my laptop. Following details prompts when I check the version using `ng --version`

```
Angular CLI: 12.2.15
Node: 14.15.0
Package Manager: npm 8.3.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1202.15 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         12.2.15 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   12.2.15 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          12.2.15 (cli-only)
```

I am currently doing a project using this angular version. Also, I need to get the message which displays after installing angular/cli, to include in an article. I don't need to upgrade angular, as I have an ongoing project using angular 12. Is `npm install -g @angular/cli` command upgrades the version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is mention the latest version of angular using following command
npm install -g @angular/cli@13.3.1
even
npm install -g @angular/cli will also update the angular to the latest stable version
one problem can be that your global version is updated with -g tag but local project version is different so try
npm install @angular/cli without the global tag

Comment: So, in my case, I need to run npm install @angular/cli@12.2.15? Am I correct?

Comment: correct it will add angular 12.2.15 locally to your project

Comment: Thanks a lot. One other thing I need to know. Is 12.2.15 global cli version? How can I find both local and global versions?

Comment: npm install -g @angular/cli@12.2.15 will add angular 12.2.15 to global packages which can be used in any project while npm install @angular/cli@12.2.15 will install angular 12.2.15 to local project and can only be used to this project. you can run both and it will add it to both global and local, but recommended is to use 12.2.15 to local project only